# Generic type use, in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a problem with the generic use I suppose,
Some code:

```
public class ObservableValue<T> extends Observable {
    private T value;

    public ObservableValue(T initial) {
        setValue(initial);
    }

    public void setValue(T newValue) {
        if (value != newValue) {
            this.value = newValue;
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers(value);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class SokobanGame implements Game, Observer {

    protected final ArrayList<GameStatusBarElement<Integer>> windowElements;

    public void nextLevel(Integer currentLevel){
        this.windowElements.get(0).getElement().setValue(currentLevel);

        for(GameStatusBarElement<Integer> element : windowElements)
            element.update();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class GameStatusBarElement<T> {
    protected final ObservableValue<T> element;

    public GameStatusBarElement(String elementText,
            ObservableValue<T> observableValue) {
        this.element = observableValue;
    }
 }
```

And that in the main implementation :

```
GameStatusBarElement<Integer> level = new GameStatusBarElement<Integer>("Level:", new ObservableValue<Integer>(1));

        GameWindow gameWindow = new GameWindow("",
                null, null, level);
}
```

So, the problem is: I cannot use `setValue(currentLevel)` (in `SokobanGame`) because of the `currentLevel` type, eclipse tell me to put something with the `T` type... But I instantiate the class of `this.windowElements.get(0).getElement()` with `new GameStatusBarElement<Integer>("Level:", new ObservableValue<Integer>(1));`, so I don't understand what's the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems fine, but I don't see the implementation of your `getElement()` method.

If your `getElement()` method is like this one:

```
public ObservableValue<T> getElement() {
    return element;
}
```

it should compile just fine.

Comment: Ho thank you, I forgot to change this getter, it was : 

public ObservableValue<?> getElement() {
    return element;
}

So, now it's work ;)